# Как запустить цикл в vba эксель с паузой без зависания ПК

Tags: vba

Пытаюсь сделать игру змейку, но не могу понять **как запустить цикл в vba эксель с паузой без зависания ПК** что бы была возможность нажать клавиши лево/право/вверх/вниз. Делаю самый простой цикл с паузой но ПК зависает после нескольких движений ячеек (закрашиваний). В какую сторону посмотреть?

```
for i=2 to 12
  for t=2 to 12
  пауза
    cells(i, t).interior.colorindex=3
    cells(i-1, t-1).interior.colorindex=0
  пауза
  next t
next i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передавайте управление системе: *DoEvents*

```
For i = 2 To 12
    For t = 2 To 12
        Call pause ' к прерыванию
        Cells(i, t).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
........
```

Пример паузы (задержка 5 секунд) с разрешением работы клавиатуры:

```
Sub pause()
Dim t As Date
    t = Timer

    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop While Timer - t < 5
End Sub
```